# retrieving resource from dotnet assembly

Tags: c#, .net, file, binary, assemblies

I created a very simple application a long time ago, in dot net. Now I need to rewrite the application with some additions, but I lost the code of previous version but I have the binary file. There is some quality images in previous version as resource within assembly.
How can I retrieve those images from assembly, to be used in new version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) trial and browse to the resources folder inside the assembly. Then you can extract any resource as you wish. Right click on any resource file ans select "Save as", which will generate a ".resources" which you can then include in your new project.

Comment: right, then will have to use resgen.exe (dot net utility) to generate .resX from .resource, and use visual studio to save the individual resource elements.

Comment: precisely. also quite useful in re-using open source resources in open source projects.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Extracting_Embedded_Image.aspx). You may also checkout [this post](http://www.csharp411.com/embedded-image-resources/) for extracting images programatically.